# Can one import FENs of positions involving checkmate into Droidfish?

Tags: software, fen

I recently copied the following curious position [(from this answer)](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/19209/13565) to clipboard, and tried pasting it in Droidfish.

```
3b1q1q/1N2PRQ1/rR3KBr/B4PP1/2Pk1r1b/1P2P1N1/2P2P2/8 w - - 0 1
```

However, the situation involved a checkmate and when I tried pasting it, Droidfish displayed an error message (**King capture possible**).

### My question

So can't I load the FEN of any position involving a checkmate in Droidfish?

Comment: It’s called FEN not situation.

Comment: @SmallChess Of course, got your point! Just using common terms! Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the FEN is wrong. In the position it should be black to move next, so in the FEN there should be a "b" instead of "w". The correct FEN would be:

3b1q1q/1N2PRQ1/rR3KBr/B4PP1/2Pk1r1b/1P2P1N1/2P2P2/8 b - -

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused before, it was the first time I had any difficulty importing a position! Thanks, +1 and I've accepted your answer!